# Unexpected R regex evaluation

Tags: regex, r

I'm working on some regular expressions using an online Regex tester (http://www.regexr.com) to help figure out the syntax.  However when I try to evaluate the pattern in R, I get a different result from what I was expecting.

The code is:

```
grepl("Brent[^a-zA-Z]", c("Brent", "Brentwood", "Brent 01"))
```

and I'm expecting: `TRUE, FALSE, TRUE` which is what I get with the online tester.  But R returns `FALSE, FALSE, TRUE`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: try `Brent(?:[^a-zA-Z]|$)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first string cannot match because `[^a-zA-Z]` has to consume exactly one character.

You can replace it with `\b` (word boundary): `\bBrent\b`.

And, if you want to allow strings like `Brent01` (without the space before the `01`), you can use lookaheads: `\bBrent(?![a-zA-Z])` (but I don't know if this feature is available in R).

Comment: Avinash's solution above works as well, but I like the lookahead version.  The only trick is that you have to add the option `perl=TRUE` to the grepl function.